# DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package and "code": 404, "message": "Not Found. Could not get object", "status": "GET_OBJECT" }

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

When I was debugging this error messaging coming on my console. Network is connected, Location is enabled. Why is that? Is that issue on Firebase Storage?

```
D/libGLESv2(11719): STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.demo.dev
W/zygote64(11719): Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/DynamiteModule(11719): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:3 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:3
I/DynamiteModule(11719): Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
W/DynamiteModule(11719): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
D/ConnectivityManager(11719): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10868, CallingPid : 11719
I/DynamiteModule(11719): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(11719): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/zygote64(11719): find the special shared library, skip check
I/zygote64(11719): find the special shared library, skip check
I/zygote64(11719): Failed to open app image /data/app/com.google.android.gms-hB2cPXA9qy2DYi6Ad6koKA==/oat/arm64/base.art Failed to open '/data/app/com.google.android.gms-hB2cPXA9qy2DYi6Ad6koKA==/oat/arm64/base.art'
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(11719): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@d4dec1
V/NativeCrypto(11719): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(11719): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller(11719): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
D/ConnectivityManager(11719): requestNetwork; CallingUid : 10868, CallingPid : 11719
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(11719): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@d4dec1
D/FirebaseAuth(11719): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 9zD91GkB5aX8jd4m428nVwOg8yB3 ).
W/Firestore(11719): (21.3.0) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: getToken aborted due to token change.
I/zygote64(11719): Do full code cache collection, code=120KB, data=84KB
I/zygote64(11719): After code cache collection, code=107KB, data=62KB
I/zygote64(11719): Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=73KB
I/zygote64(11719): After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=73KB
I/zygote64(11719): Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
D/ViewRootImpl@24391fb[MainActivity](11719): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 495703769088} changed=false
I/System.out(11719): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(11719): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
E/StorageException(11719): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(11719): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(11719):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(11719): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(11719): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(11719):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
E/StorageException(11719):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
E/StorageException(11719):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
E/StorageException(11719):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
E/StorageException(11719):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
E/StorageException(11719):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:70)
E/StorageException(11719):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:62)
E/StorageException(11719):  at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:74)
E/StorageException(11719):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
E/StorageException(11719):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
E/StorageException(11719):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1):

The object you are trying to read from Firebase Storage Bucket does not exist at the path/location. Hence the error
`Object does not exist at location.`
Also The HTTP Error Code 404.
So you can check the path in your code and check the object in firebase storage console ( refresh page every time you perform a upload or delete operation)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I was checking the documentation and my problem was the `MinSDK` Version:
I go to `android/app/build.gradle` and there I change the `minSdkVersion: 16` to `minSdkVersion: 21`, because firebase need that at least `MinSDK Version 19`.